# I'm trying to convert a text file to dictionary or a list Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have the following text file datafile.txt

```
Pin AccountNumber   FirstName   LastName    AccountBalance      AccountType       
2221    436115      Bob         Smith       100.00              Checking
```

I need to load the text file and load it into a dictionary with the pin as the key. This is what I have so far and I do not understand how to proceed

```
bData = open('datafile.txt')

for line in bData:
    bInfo = line.split()
    print(bData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, skip the title line

```
next(bData)
```

then build the dict in one line using dict comprehension and star unpacking (python 3):

```
d = {k:v for k,*v in (line.split() for line in bData)}
```

python 2 compliant:

```
d = {s[0]:s[1:] for s in (line.split() for line in f)}
```

result:

```
{'2221': ['436115', 'Bob', 'Smith', '100.00', 'Checking']}
```

(you need to put more lines to get more keys of course)

Comment: You might add a version that works in Python2 as well.

Comment: I love one/two line answers, +1. Also, I liked the use of `next()`, +1 again.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers check OP data, it's separated by 1 or more tab chars. `split` works fine here but csv module creates extra empty cells, so it cannot be used here.